# Differense between Motion API and Accelerometer in Windows Phone

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone, accelerometer

I use Motion API in my application for Windows Phone, but not all devices is support Motion API. However in Windows Phone exists Accelerometer API that supports most devices.

What difference between this APIs for my using? Please see this two code blocks:

Using Motion API:

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    if (motion == null)
    {
        motion = new Motion();
        motion.TimeBetweenUpdates = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(15);
        motion.CurrentValueChanged += OnSensorReadingChangedMotion;
        motion.Start();
    }         
}

private void OnSensorReadingChangedMotion(object sender, SensorReadingEventArgs<MotionReading> e)
{
    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => CurrentValueChangedMotion(e.Gravity.X, e.Gravity.Y, e.Gravity.Z));
}
```

And using Accelerometer:

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
{
     if (_accelerometer == null)
     {
        _accelerometer = new Accelerometer();
     }

    _accelerometer.TimeBetweenUpdates = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(15);
    _accelerometer.CurrentValueChanged += OnSensorReadingChangedAccel;

    _accelerometer.Start();       
}

 private void OnSensorReadingChangedAccel(object sender, SensorReadingEventArgs<AccelerometerReading> sensorReadingEventArgs)
 {
     Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => CurrentValueChangedAccelerometer(sensorReadingEventArgs.SensorReading.Acceleration.X, sensorReadingEventArgs.SensorReading.Acceleration.Y, sensorReadingEventArgs.SensorReading.Acceleration.Z));
 }
```

I found that the accelerometer readings is the more volatile.
I need to use a vector {x, y, z} for my app. What is actually the difference between

```
{.SensorReading.Acceleration.X, .SensorReading.Acceleration.Y,.SensorReading.Acceleration.Z}
```

and

```
{e.Gravity.X, e.Gravity.Y, e.Gravity.Z}
```

?

What difference between Motion API and Accelerometer, if I use a similar vector?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the difference :

`Acceleration` property from accelerometer includes resultant of gravity force as well as forces caused by phone movements, when `Gravity` property from Motion API is *only* gravity force (calculated using multiple sensors then separated from forces caused by phone movements).

According to [this MSDN post](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202968%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) :

> The Accelerometer sensor detects the force of gravity along with any forces resulting from the movement of the phone. The combined motion API, accessed using the Motion class, uses multiple device sensors to separate the gravity vector from the device acceleration and allows you to easily determine the current attitude (yaw, pitch, and roll) of the device.

Comment: Thank you! I think that I should to use Motion API if it possible, and Accelerometer, if Motion API is impossible? My application is Level, for measuring phone angle, like this [Similar app](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/store/app/level/c14e93aa-27d7-df11-a844-00237de2db9e)

Comment: agree, use Motion API for that purpose whenever possible, so that the application can get clean gravity force value to measure angle more accurately.